# Self in Swift - a confusion

Tags: swift

I've been playing around with concepts of mutability and self in Swift Playground and wrote this code snippet:

```
var _message = "Outside Message"

struct MyStruct {
  var _message  = "Inside Message"
  var message: String {
    mutating get {
      print(_message)
      print(self._message)

      _message = "New Message for Outside"
      self._message = "New Message for Inside"

      return self._message
    }
  }
}

var aStruct = MyStruct()
print("Result: \(aStruct.message)")
```

And I get the output:

> Inside Message
>
> Inside Message
>
> Result: New Message for Inside

I don't understand why within myStruct, self has no affect (since we always seem to reference the inner _message variable) and if so, how would one reference the outer _message variable from within the Message property?

Comment: Please make sure that you follow naming conventions when sharing code. Types should start with an UpperCase letter. Variable names and functions should start with a lowerCase letter. It makes it much easier to parse when reading it.

Answer (score 1):

> why within myStruct, `self` has no affect (since we always seem to reference the inner _message variable)

It does have an effect. It means *the current instance of this struct*. The "inner" `_message` is an *instance property*, so `self._message` refers to it. But in the contexts where you are using it, it is optional; a message without a recipient is assumed to have *self* as its recipient. So in those contexts it makes no difference whether you include or omit it; you are *still* referring to `self._message` regardless.

> how would one reference the outer `_message` variable from within the Message property

You can't. By declaring an instance property with the same name, you have *overshadowed* it, effectively cutting off your own access to it from within the struct.

The "outer" variable, on the other hand, is *global*. It is not part of any object. Thus it is not namespaced and there is no way to refer to it if you overshadow it. This is one of many reasons why globals are bad. Don't use them.

Comment: I think the outer `_message` can still be accessed by using `ModuleName._message`, right?

Comment: What's the module name in a playground?

Comment: Oh I didn't notice this was in a playground!

Answer (score 0):

In `Swift` self is implicit and scope will set the precedence of what variable names refer to.

In your example you have two properties called `_message`.

Inside the type `MyStruct` both `_message` and `self._message` refer to the property on `MyStruct`.

Inside the struct there is no way to refer to the outside `_message` property.